# How can I pick only existing JSON branches in Play 2.4 (Scala)?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.4

### Edited question (simplified)

I get an input JSON object via a REST API and want to transform this into a new validated JSON object. All properties/branches are optional.

My Play 2.4 action so far:

```
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json.Reads._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

// [...]

def updateUser(id: String) = Action(parse.json) { request =>
    /** Name validaton */
    val nameReads: Reads[JsString] = Reads.of[JsString] keepAnd
        Reads.minLength[String](2) keepAnd
        Reads.maxLength[String](20) keepAnd
        Reads.pattern("""[a-z]*""".r)

    /** Age validaton */
    val ageReads: Reads[JsNumber] = Reads.of[JsNumber] keepAnd
        Reads.min(18) keepAnd
        Reads.max(128)

    /** Transformer */
    val transformUser: Reads[JsObject] = (
        (__ \ 'name).json.pickBranch(nameReads) and
        (__ \ 'age).json.pickBranch(ageReads)
    ).reduce

    // I guess I'd like to have something like this:
    // val transformUser: Reads[JsObject] = (
    //  (__ \ 'name).json.pickBranchIfExists(nameReads) and
    //  (__ \ 'age).json.pickBranchIfExists(ageReads)
    // ).reduce

    val inputJson: JsValue = request.body
    inputJson.transform(transformUser).map { resultJsObj =>
        Ok(resultJsObj)
    } recoverTotal { err =>
        val errJsObj: JsObject = JsError.toJson(err)
        BadRequest(errJsObj)
    }
}
```

Now I'm looking for something that is neither `pickBranch`, nor `prune`, more something like `pickBranchIfExsists`. Is this possible?